# application profiling and usage monitoring

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring

I am looking for an application that can crawl a network and list what applications are installed on each of those computers and monitor how often they are used. An application that can do either of those tasks is also appreciated.

For example

Computer A

- Internet Explorer 8.0 - 3 hours
- Microsoft Word 2010 - 5 hours
- Microsoft Excel 2010 - 0 hours
- . . .

Answer (score 1):

Althought full use is not free [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) 
The Demo will most definetly work with the server client option.